# Groovy code - import statement not needed?

Tags: java, groovy

I created a groovy class with a method that returns `Collection<String>`. It works, but it's weird that there is no `Collection` in the import statements.

The class inherits a super class. That super class (java) does have the import statement for collection: `import java.util.Collection;`

Is it the expected behavior?

Does java or groovy inherit imports too? I doubt that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No imports are not inherited between classes.

In `Groovy` all of the below packages are imported by default.

- java.io.*
- java.lang.*
- java.math.BigDecimal
- java.math.BigInteger
- java.net.*
- java.util.* (which includes `Collection`)
- groovy.lang.*
- groovy.util.*

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [default imports.](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java) This is expected behavior. There's no import inheritance. All these packages are imported for every class.